# AVR USART wait for AVR's reponse to continue text stream

Tags: avr, atmega, communication, data, terminal

## AVR USART wait for AVR's reponse to continue protocol

I am doing a senior project, and I need to send a large text file **line by line** to an AVR (atmega32) which will control a piano using ~36 solenoids and shift registers. This needs to be done automatically and very fast. I cannot mannually input the text in the terminal. I need to send 3 strings, line by line to an AVR and wait between each line for a confirmation to continue form the AVR.

- The text file is a converted midi file which contains 3 usefull information (the time of the event, the note, and the status (press note or unpress). The text file looks like this:

> 213, 25, ON
>   321, 25, OFF
>   521, 36, ON --> which represents play the Note C at time = 521 ms
>   
>   Where the first string is the time of the event, the second is the note and the third is the status of the note

**The protocol would need to look like this:**

- The PC sends 3 string to the AVR. So total of 3 USART transfers.
- The PC waits for AVR to send an aknowledgement to continue transfering **the next line of text**
- The AVR plays the "event" on the piano and at the end send a confirmation to the PC to send the next lines of text

**How is this achievable?**

## **Why am I doing this?**

The problem is that I can't store all the text file in an array of because the AVR is too small(the largest atmega is 512Kb if I recall well)
I need to stream the text file using the terminal (Hyperterminal) line by line. 
**BUT** how to send a line using the terminal, wait until the atmega finished the process --> send a confirmation back to the PC to stream the next line?

Comment: Are you waiting until you receive a full line before processing it? And if so, why?

Comment: Why are you converting the MIDI to text? Why not have the AVR interpret the MIDI data directly, which would arguably be much simpler? After all, sending music over a serial port is exactly what MIDI was designed for!

Comment: Yes, because 1 line will give me enough information to stream bit into a shift register. for instance, The C note will represent 000000100 in the mapped solenoids configuration.

Comment: @DaveTweed Because I am not sending MIDI to FROM the AVR. The AVR controls SOLENOIDS

Comment: @DaveTweed Are you saying I can do MIDI --> USART --> AVR --> SOLENOIDS???

Comment: What's the difference between MIDI→text→USART→AVR→solenoids and MIDI→USART→AVR→solenoids other than the extra conversion step? And you don't need a full line before you start processing it; do it byte by byte instead.

Comment: Yes, if you use a sequencer program to send the music out the host computer's MIDI port, you can receive this data using the AVR's USART. You just need to set the USART data rate to 31.250 kbps and build a [simple hardware interface](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9595). (I know you're not using Arduino specifically, but you can get the schematic of the part you need here.) Furthermore, the computer will automatically handle the note timing (flow control) for you. In addition, you'll also be able to use any other MIDI-enabled device to control your piano.

Comment: If you want to use hypterminal, you'll need to implement something it supports, such as XON/XOFF (software) or possibly RTS/CTS (hardware).  Beware that if you use a USB-serial converter a reply-required protocol will slow you down substantially.  However, another option is to use native USB (instead of USB-serial), in which case you can decline to acknowledge a USB packet until you have consumed it and are ready for another.  If you implement a known USB-serial protocol, you can then use hyperterminal as your sender.  But consider dropping hyperterminal and writing your own sender program.

Comment: Or you could implement a USB MIDI device and let a software sequencer handle it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I don't have any MIDI device to control. The solenoids are homemade for the project, that's why I need to convert MIDI to text. Then use this text to control shift registers

Comment: That's why you turn the MCU into a MIDI device.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams but our input is not a MIDI signal. Its a midi file. How to I do that?

Comment: You use a MIDI sequencer to turn the MIDI file into a MIDI signal.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams , OK, then how to I used this signal to control the Solenoids?

Comment: You have the AVR interpret the MIDI signal and energize them as appropriate.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams thats the problem, I can't find any MIDI interpreter. Only the oposite is popular.

Comment: Then you need to add the effort to write it into your budget.

Comment: @DaveTweed , Ok, but then how can I interpret the inputted MIDI? I don't want to ouput MIDI, I;m outputting bits.

Comment: What @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams said. And what I said to start with, 2 hours ago. You write a MIDI interpreter, which is vastly simpler than writing a text interpreter. You don't need to implement the entire [MIDI specification](http://oktopus.hu/uploaded/Tudastar/MIDI%201.0%20Detailed%20Specification.pdf), just "note on" and "note off" messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is "flow control" or "handshaking".

For USART, you can use hardware flow control with [RTS/CTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232#RTS.2FCTS_handshaking), but many USART implementations today omit them. If you've finished you hardware and without these pins connected, you may try "[software flow control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control)" with "XON/XOFF", because these two codes won't appear in your text file (they are non-printable character). So use them as flow control is possible. But compared to hardware flow control, the later may be a little slower.

The main limitation with you it's your MCU is not strong enough to handle the entire file, so parse the file on PC end is reasonable.

If you don't want to dive into a complicated USART programm on PC, you can try [Tera Term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tera_Term), an open-source, programmable, handy "Hyperterminal" killer.

Comment: Does Tera Term provide a functionality read a text file? Because if I recall we'll, terminals require manual input for character transfer right? Thanks for the info by the way!

Comment: Yes, you can do simple programing in Tera Term, and it supports file reading. Do Hyperterminal need manual input.